# Copying Attributes from Superclass Instance while Inheriting?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, python-3.4, superclass

I'm trying to make a subclass that inherits from an instance of its superclass, and bases the majority of its attributes on the superclass attributes.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, thing, d):
        self.a = thing.a
        self.b = thing.b
        self.c = thing.c
        self.d = d
```

Is there a more concise way to make the `a`, `b`, and `c` declarations inside `ThingWithD.__init__()`?

Comment: @yole: The ThingWithD class will _not_ "inherit" the attributes unless it calls the superclass's `__init__()` method so they're created (or does it itself as shown in the OP's question).

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  If `ThingWithD` inherits from `Thing`, it will already get the attributes defined in `Thing.__init__`, as long as you use `super` to call the superclass `__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most concise—and object-oriented—way would probably be to just call the superclass's `__init__()` method and avoid the repetition:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, thing, d):
        super().__init__(thing.a, thing.b, thing.c)  # Python 3 only
        self.d = d

thing = Thing(1, 2, 3)
thing_with_d = ThingWithD(thing, 4)
print('{}, {}'.format(thing_with_d.a, thing_with_d.d)) # -> 1, 4
```

To do the same thing in Python 2.x, you would need to make `Thing` a new-style class by explicitly specifying its base class as `object` and change the call to the superclass constructor as shown below.

If you make both of these modifications, the same code will work in both Python 2 and 3.

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, thing, d):
        super(ThingWithD, self).__init__(thing.a, thing.b, thing.c)
        self.d = d
```

Answer (score 1):

With class `Thing` defined as such:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I can think of 3 ways to do achieve what you are asking using classical inheritence. The first, is to take advantage of your known arguments and explicitly index `args` to pull out a to c, and d, like so:

```
class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.d = args[-1]
        a_to_c = args[:-1]
        super().__init__(*a_to_c)


thing_with_d = ThingWithD(1,2,3,4)
thing_with_d.a # 1
thing_with_d.d # 4
```

The second, and best way, would be to convert your params to keyword arguments so that they can be more easily mixed and matched. This is the most scalable solution, and could pave the way for `ThingWithE` and `ThingWithF`.

```
class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, d=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.d = d


thing_with_d = ThingWithD(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
thing_with_d.a # 1
thing_with_d.d # 4
```

The last way, which seems closest to what you already tried, is to use `ThingWithD` as a factory class that adds d to a class self referentially.

```
class ThingWithD(Thing):
    def __init__(self, thing, d):
        super().__init__(thing.a, thing.b, thing.c)
        self.d = d

thing = Thing(1,2,3)
thing_with_d = ThingWithD(thing, 4)
thing_with_d.a # 1
thing_with_d.d # 4
```

This is a strange approach, because here we are actually creating a copy of the original `thing` instance, and its unclear why we are inheriting from `Thing` at all. Instead, we could use a function that does the following.

```
def add_d_to_thing(thing, d):
    thing.d = d
    return thing

thing = Thing(1,2,3)
thing_with_d = add_d_to_thing(thing, 4)
thing_with_d.a # 1
thing_with_d.d # 4
```

This would return the same instance of thing, would add a `d` attribute, and is easier to read.

Comment: In Python 2, `def __init__(self, *args, d):` is invalid syntax, and in Python 3 `ThingWithD(1,2,3,4)` causes a `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'd'` — so you obviously never tried running your code.

Comment: @martineau OP tagged the post as `python-3.4` so the syntax is correct. As to the second part, you're right, thanks for the assist! I always forget that *args must be used as the last positional argument in a function/method definition, with everything to its right being a keyword. I've updated my answer with several working examples.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the question was tagged python 3.4, but as you acknowledged it was also incorrect for that version, too. For what it's worth, I think those `thing_with_d.a # 1` lines you have at the end of every one of your code snippets would be better if they were changed to something like `print(thing_with_d.a) # 1` so they actually produced some output. You could even print two values at once `print(thing_with_d.a, thing_with_d.d)  # -> 1 4`—what a concept!